# How to take string format from command line?

Tags: jq

```
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)
```

I want to pass string format from the command line of jq, instead of embedding the format in string interpolation.

Let's say the format string is "my string %s". How to modify the following jq command to take the format string in its argument so that the output will be "my string x"?

```
jq --arg format "my string %s" -r -e . <<< '"x"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your (dynamic) jq expression inside `\(…)`, which in turn is part of a (static) string expression `"…"`. If all you want is passing on the input, use the identity function `.`, and your example should read

```sh
jq -r -e '"my string \(.)"' <<< '"x"'
```

```
my string x
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8J3qqLxUcy)

---

Having `"my string %s"` as a parameter string, you cannot use it for string interpolation, as string interpolation is a language construct, and `jq` does not provide an `eval` (or similar) function to evaluate a variable's content as code.

What you can do instead is to (naively) replace `%s` with something else using `sub` or `gsub`:

```sh
jq -r -e -n --arg f "my string %s" '$f | sub("%s"; input)' <<< '"x"'
```

```
my string x
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LRUkgSQoQc)

Comment: "my string %s" must be in --arg as in `--arg format "my string %s"`. It can not be in a jq expression.

Comment: `jq` does not have an `eval` (or similar) function to evaluate a variable's content as `jq` code.

Comment: So this justifies adding printf is a legitimate request? The github link claim that string interpolation solves 99% of the problems. But I think it is better off just add printf instead of introducing string interpolation which does not solve all the problems.

Comment: Of course the number 99% is arguable, but it definitely has its uses. `printf` just follows a diferent logic (formatting with placeholders etc.) which is not applicable here. But with string interpolation you can have full-featured code within a string, which makes it evenly (if not even more) powerful. But as the logical approaches differ heavily, you simply cannot claim that they are "100%" interchangeable.

Comment: Sprintf can be added to support the things asked in this question. For example, in this case, it can be just `jq --argstr format "my string %s" -r -e '. as $y | sprintf($format, $y)' <<< '"x"'`. Is there a problem to add `printf`to jq?

Comment: You have referenced https://stedolan.github.io/jq, but this implementaion of `jq` does not have neither an `--argstr` option, nor a `sprintf` function. Maybe you are talking about a different implementation of `jq`? (https://github.com/itchyny/gojq for example?)

Comment: I was talking about hypothetically, sprintf could be added there. --argstr was a typo. It should have been --arg.

Comment: How to make your sub appoach work for more complex cases? I couldn't make this work `jq -r --arg format "my string %s" -e 'if type=="object" then $format | sub("%s"; input|.x) else . end' <<< '{"x":"y"}'` How to fix it?

Comment: You may want to define your own function: `jq -r --arg format "my string %s" 'def fmt($f): . as $in | $f |  sub("%s"; $in); .x | fmt($format)' <<< '{"x":"y"}'`